# Definite Integral of $\sin(\sin x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I recently came across this problem:

Prove that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(\sin y) dy \leq 1$.

However, from my understanding, the expression $\sin(\sin y)$ does not have an indefinite integral ([How to find the indefinite integral of sin(sin(x))dx?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782139/how-to-find-the-indefinite-integral-of-sinsinxdx)). So, how will we go about solving the above problem using just the Riemann sums?

Comment: Note that you're not being asked to evaluate the integral, only to bound it

Comment: That is true. So, the next step should be to compare it with a function that is known?

Comment: Wolfy says that the integral is $ (π H_0(1))/2≈0.893244$ so it is fairly close to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x) = \sin(\sin x)$. We know that $0 \le \sin x \le x$. As $\sin x$ is increasing on $[0, \pi/2]$, $0 \le f(x) \le \sin x$ on this interval.

Taking the integral, you're done.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty straightforward from here. Thank you. But do you think there might be a way of going about it without integrating $sinx$?

Comment: You can check my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650505/prove-an-integral-is-bounded/3650529#3650529)  without integrating $sinx$  :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a pretty smart way of going about it.