# Can $ \int \sin(x)+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^n\frac{\sin^{(2n+1)}(x)}{(2n+1)!} dx$ be evaluated in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation

How do you go about integrating this and can it even be done with elementary functions?
$$
\int \sin(x)+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^n\frac{\sin^{(2n+1)}(x)}{(2n+1)!} dx.
$$

I understand the concept of $$ \int \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sin^n (x) dx =\int \frac{dx}{1-\sin x}$$ but I have no clue if that will even help but its the first idea I had to try and clean it up or even how to use it to clean it up.

Additionally this is very similar to integrating $ \int \sin (\sin (x)) $ since the sum is so close to the Taylor series summation of $\sin (x)$ the only difference being $\sin (x)$ is just $x$, not sure if that would help but I'm trying to add as much as I know.

Comment: Use $sinx=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ to get summation.

Comment: The integrand is just $\sin(\sin(x))$ (as you noticed), which likely has no elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Look also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2782139).

Comment: Just to clarify because some of the answers are confused, is the $(2n+1)$ the derivative or is it a power?

Comment: (2n + 1) is the power as in (sin x) ^ (2n + 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^n\frac{t^{(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}= \sin (t)-t$$

So, as you noticed, the problem is "simply" to compute
$$I=\int \sin(\sin(x))\,dx$$ which cannot be obtained aven using special functions.

If it was for definite integrals, the problem would be different since
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sin(\sin(x))\,dx=\frac{\pi  }{2}\pmb{H}_0(1)$$ where appears  the Struve function.

But, from the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877408/fourier-series-sin-sinx/877417#877417), we have, using Fourier series,
$$\color{blue}{\sin(\sin(x)) = 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty J_{2k+1}(1)\sin \left((2k+1)x\right)}$$ which makes
$$I=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ J_{2 k+1}(1) }{2 k+1}\cos ((2 k+1) x)$$
and the coefficients vary so fast that very few terms would be sufficient for a definite integral.

For example, using only three terms and integrating from $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$ would give $0.8932437398$ while the exact value given above is $0.8932437410$.